# Scheduling an item on different days org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to place a list-item scheduled for different days? The item should then be displayed when I hit `C-c a a` for `agenda-view`. I don΄t mean a date that is repeated on a regular basis, or a range, which both are described in the manual under [Timestamps, deadlines, and scheduling](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Timestamps), but dates that are scheduled in a random way.

What I did was place three `SCHEDULED` below the date:

```
* TODO Get schwifty
SCHEDULED: <2018-08-04 Sa>
SCHEDULED: <2018-08-06 Mo>
SCHEDULED: <2018-08-09 Th>
```

This makes them available `agenda-view`, but the second and third entry look a bit odd as they lack the `SCHEDULED`. Are there any drawbacks to what I did or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If "Get Schwifty" is a TODO entry, why group it?
It will be better to have seperate entries i.e:

```
*TODO Get Schwifty <2018-08-04>
*TODO Get Schwifty <2018-08-06>
*TODO Get Schwifty <2018-08-09>
```

This way completion will be documented and useful in the agenda.

or have a list with a button:

```
** TODO Get another Shwifty
- [ ] <2018-08-04>
- [ ] <2018-08-06>
- [ ] <2018-08-09>
```

Both methods shows in the agenda because of the type of time stamp, scheduling is different, as per the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html):

> Scheduling an item in Org mode should not be understood in the same way that we understand scheduling a meeting. Setting a date for a meeting is just a simple appointment, you should mark this entry with a simple plain timestamp, to get this item shown on the date where it applies. This is a frequent misunderstanding by Org users. In Org mode, scheduling means setting a date when you want to start working on an action item.